# Webpack, Gulp, and React loading errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, gulp

My setup is below. If I run `gulp` in the directory with these files, then I get a boatload of errors that look like the following. They all have a similar signature but are failing to find a different part of react-bootstrap, react-dom, or the like.

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-bootstrap/lib/Input' in '...a/scripts/components'
 @ ./a/scripts/components/SearchBar.js 7:12-48
 @ ./a/scripts/pages/HomePage.js
 @ ./a/scripts/routes.js
 @ ./a/scripts/index.js
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8083 webpack/hot/only-dev-server ./a/scripts/index
```

This makes me think it's to do with the loader. And in fact, if I run `npm install`, then after verifying that everything is installed and making a bundle.js, this error occurs:

```
ERROR in ./a/scripts/index.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (19:15)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| 
| Router.run(routes, Router.HistoryLocation, function(Handler) {
|   React.render(<Handler />, document.getElementById('entry'));
| });
| 
 @ multi ./a/scripts/index
```

Which also suggests it's with the loader. I've since spent a lot of time trying to figure out why the loader wouldn't be working and am coming up blank. Help would be greatly appreciated.

package.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.12.7",
    "npm": "2.7.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "gulp build"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "none",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.8",
    "del": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.6",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^4.1.0",
    "gulp-cache": "^1.0.2",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^3.9.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.5.2",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^4.1.0",
    "gulp-jshint": "^2.1.0",
    "gulp-livereload": "^3.8.0",
    "gulp-notify": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-ruby-sass": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.0",
    "jsx": "^0.9.89",
    "jsx-loader": "^0.13.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.9.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "plugin-error": "^0.1.2",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^3.1.3",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-script-loader": "^0.0.1",
    "run-sequence": "^2.2.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "sass-material-colors": "0.0.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.1",
    "superagent": "^3.8.2",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "url-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.10.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1"
  },
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
    "presets": ["env", "react"]
}
```

gulpfile.babel.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename');
var log = require('fancy-log');
var PluginError = require('plugin-error');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
var webpackConfig = require("./webpack.config.js");
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
var path = require('path');
var del = require('del');

var watch = true;
var verbose = true;

// Default to Dev Server
gulp.task('default', ["js-dev-server"]);

// Clean output directory
gulp.task('clean', () => del(['a/static/js/build/*', 'a/static/css/*'], {dot:true}))

gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return sass('a/static/scss/styles.scss', { style: 'expanded' })
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('a/static/css'))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(cleanCSS())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('a/static/css'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('a/static/scss/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
});

gulp.task('bundle', function() {
  function bundle(err, stats) {
    if (err) {
      throw new PluginError("build", err);
    }

    console.log(stats.toString({
      colors: true,
      hash: verbose,
      version: verbose,
      timings: verbose,
      chunks: verbose,
      chunkModules: verbose,
      cached: verbose,
      cachedAssets: verbose
    }));
  }

  webpack(webpackConfig).run(bundle)
});

gulp.task('build', ['clean'], cb => { runSequence(['styles', 'bundle']); });

gulp.task("js-dev-server", function(callback){
  // modify some webpack config options
  var myConfig = Object.create(webpackConfig);
  myConfig.devtool = "eval-source-map";
  myConfig.entry = [
      'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8083',
      'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
      './a/scripts/index'
  ];
  myConfig.plugins = [
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
      new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({debug: true})
  ];
  myConfig.output['publicPath'] = "http://localhost:8083/static/js/build/"
  myConfig.module = {
      loaders: [
          {
              test: /\.jsx?$/,
              exclude: /node_modules/,
              loaders: ['react-hot-loader/webpack', 'jsx-loader?harmony', 'babel-loader']
          },
        { test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
          loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=a/font-woff" },
        { test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
          loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=a/font-woff" },
        { test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
          loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=a/octet-stream" },
        { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
          loader: "file-loader" },
        { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
          loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=image/svg+xml" },
        { test: /\.scss$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?includePaths[]=" +
          path.resolve(__dirname, "./a/static/scss/")
        }
    ]
  };

  // Start a webpack-dev-server
  new WebpackDevServer(webpack(myConfig), {
    publicPath: "http://localhost:8083/static/js/build/",
    stats: {
      colors: true
    },
    inline: true,
    hot: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: 'http://localhost:5000/'
  }).listen(8083, "localhost", function(err) {
    if(err) throw new PluginError("webpack-dev-server", err);
    log("[webpack-dev-server]",
        "http://localhost:8083/webpack-dev-server/index.html");
  });
});
```

webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var DEBUG = true;

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        __dirname + '/a/scripts/index'
    ],
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/a/static/js/build',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({sourceMap: false,
                                             output: {comments: false}}),
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
        modules: ['node_modules', 'web_modules', 'scripts', 'lib'],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\*.js.x?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loaders: (DEBUG ? ['react-hot-loader/webpack'] : []).concat(['babel-loader'])
            },
            { test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff" },
            { test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff" },
            { test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=application/octet-stream" },
            { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "file-loader" },
            { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=image/svg+xml" },
            { test: /\.scss$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?includePaths[]=" +
              path.resolve(__dirname, "./a/static/scss/")
            }
        ]
    },
    externals: {
        "jquery": "jQuery"
    }
};
```

index.js

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react'),
    Router = require('react-router'),
    routes = require('routes');

// set up in order to receive actions
var NotificationStore = require('stores/NotificationStore');

require('csrf'); // injects CSRF token into all $.ajax calls

require('../static/scss/playground.scss'); // loads stylesheet into JS

Router.run(routes, Router.HistoryLocation, function(Handler) {
  React.render(<Handler />, document.getElementById('entry'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to your babel setup. You need to install [`babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx) and adjust your `.babelrc` file. Like this:

```
{
  "presets": ["env", "es2015", "react"],
  "plugins": ["transform-react-jsx", "transform-object-rest-spread"]

}
```

example webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path')

const config = {
  entry: {
    app: ['whatwg-fetch','./src/index.js'],
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './public'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      },
    ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'app.bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')
  }
}

module.exports = config
```

example package.json:

```
{
  "name": "react-news-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "get news and sentiment from headline articles",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --watch",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --port 3000"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "api",
    "react"
  ],
  "author": "Stephen Collins",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "^22.0.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.17",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.8",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "eslint": "^4.15.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.9.0",
    "jest": "^22.0.4",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "sinon": "^4.1.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.1",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.10.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't solve the issue. Any other ideas?

Comment: I added my entire set up for an app I'm working on, for my webpack.config.js, package.json, and .babelrc to help clarify. What is the error you're getting now, or are you getting the same error?

Comment: It's the same error. I'll look through your setup and see if anything triggers.